# How to add data to a custom field at the wp_users table?

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, database

How to add data to a custom field at the wp_users table?

I already add a new field to the wp_users table but I don't know how to add the data to this field I want to use something like add_user_meta.

Any idea?

Comment: You don't want to modify the existing WordPress tables, because there is no guarantee that WordPress won't change something in the future that will completely collide with what you're doing. The correct way is, in fact, to store meta data in `wp_usermeta` or to create another table all together if that doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** add a `field` to the database table. You can only add a `row` or `column`, and neither are supposed to be added directly to the database, especially `column`!

With `add_user_meta` you are adding a new `row` but to the `wp_usermeta` table, and that should be sufficient for any extra required fields. This table is meant to be used for extending the user's profile with any amount of custom data, since it is `key => value` structured.

Again, if you add any `column` to the `wp_users` table, you can't access this data using native WordPress functions. You can only get it by writing a custom SQL query, but I don't think you actually need this.

Comment: A `field` is the same thing as a `column`

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in using the add_user_meta() function. You can use it to pass the field name, value and the user id it is to be associated with.

Another option, if you are creating a meta box for custom information on the user profile page would be to use an existing library. Something like CMB2 will handle this really well.

https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2

Comment: Sorry but I think you can't understand me I already add the field into the database at the wp_users table the issue that I can't add the data to this field, add_user_meta function is used to add the meta to user not to add the data into wp_users

Comment: How have you created the custom field for users? Most of the metadata for users, including custom fields is stored in the user_meta table.